# DataFrame width should match the page width in jupyter book

Tags: python, html, dataframe, html-table, jupyterbook

I have many DataFrames which I want to show in a jupyter book. The length of the values in the DataFrames vary a lot.
Currently the output looks like this: [current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hJD6.png).

What I actually want is, that all Data Frames have the same width. I managed to change the column width but not the width of the whole table.

This is my current code:

```
category_one_df.set_properties(**{'width': '50%'})
category_two_df.set_properties(**{'width': '50%'})
category_three_df.set_properties(**{'width': '50%'})
```

Thanks for your help!